# Compiled Python function Executable is not single file and does not run

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3,7 and I am trying to compile my python function to one EXEcutable so it can be run by any user. The app should run either in CMD or Powershell, Later I will make it run as desktop/mobile app when i learn Gui in Python.
Code is working as it should, as far as i know. But when i compile it with:  `pyinstaller --onefile --window trackingap.py`

```
def start_setup():
    scan = input()
    try:
        while True:


            if len(scan) == 12 and scan[0:6] == "ZWABXK":
                print("XDP Channel")
                start_setup(),
            elif len(scan) == 13 and (scan[0:3] == "VC2", scan[0:4] == "FQ8"):
                print("Royal Mail Parcel")
                start_setup(),
            elif (len(scan) == (13 or 21)) and (scan[0:4] == "3703", scan[0:4] == "UG08"):
                print("Royal Mail Large Letter"),
            elif len(scan) == 14 and scan.isdigit():
                print("DPD")
                start_setup(),
            elif (len(scan) == 10 or len(scan) == 13 or len(scan) == 18 or len(scan) == 20) \
                    and (scan[0:4] == "1808", scan[0:4] == "1809",
                         scan[0:4] == "9283", scan[0:4] == "3404",
                         scan[0:4] == "CM50", scan[0:6] == "003404"):
                print("DHL")
                start_setup(),
            elif (len(scan) == 15 or len(scan) == 16) and scan.isdigit():
                print("Hermes")
                start_setup(),
            elif len(scan) == 19 and scan[0:7] == "JJD0002":
                print("Yodel")
                start_setup(),
            else:
                print("Not recognized!!!")
                start_setup()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
start_setup()
```

I will get multiple files what are not even working, Do I need to import there some aditional libraries?
There is a TXT file with following:

> This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does
> not necessarily mean this module is required for running you program.
> Python and Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or
> optional modules. For example the module 'ntpath' only exists on
> Windows, whereas the module 'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.
>
> Types if import:
>
> - top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
> - conditional: imported within an if-statement
> - delayed: imported from within a function
> - optional: imported within a try-except-statement
>
> IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a
> basis for
> yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!
>
> missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess
> (conditional) missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy
> (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional) missing module named pwd -
> imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional),
> tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser
> (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed) missing
> module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional) missing
> module named resource - imported by posix (top-level) missing module
> named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional) missing
> module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
> missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed,
> conditional, optional) missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by
> platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
> missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed) missing
> module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
> missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed,
> optional) missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported
> by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc
> (optional) excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by
> importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional) missing module named
> readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code
> (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional) missing
> module named org - imported by pickle (optional)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert your code to .exe, I think it worked
here you have download link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/iblphas3bjw13m7/nahaku.exe/file

Comment: what compiler or commands you used to compile it please ?

Comment: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "file path"   

Only that I do not fully know these commands, because I use the generator of this code, i.e. auto py to exe

Comment: the point is that you wrote that it should hide the consoles, while this application is console :)

Comment: not sure if i understand. I want it to run in console, but the pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  does not work either. Where did i wrote that it should hide console please? PS. I did not run the file you posted, as i do not trust you sorry.

Comment: there is "--window" in the command you provided in the question, so that means it is supposed to hide the console as it should be "--console" instead of "--window"
PS I'm sorry you don't trust me, but you have the right to do so because we don't know each other :)

Comment: now I understand, but still i cannot compile it, frankly I did reinstall my python today, i used previously Anaconda, VS code but i had issues with virtual environments, I completly uninnstall it today and installed new Pycharm, it works fine, but I somehow probably uninstall some librarys with Anaconda and VS code. Because when i compiled similar file before it was in one file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.... after I reinstalled the Pycharm, i did not put the PATH to the windows Environment variables. when i added path to python it worked.